# Integration of $1/x$ becomes $\ln(x) + \ln(C)$?

Tags: integration

Why is
$$
\int\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{3-x}  dx= \ln(x) - \ln(3-x) + \ln(C) \;?
$$
Isn't it
$$
\ln(x) - \ln(3-x) + C \;?
$$

Comment: Those are the same thing. $C$ is an arbitrary constant. (You could quibble about the sign of $C$ in the former expression, but meh.)

Comment: Wait so the antiderivative of 1/x could also be presented as ln (x) +ln C?

Comment: or as $\ln Cx$ using the rules for logarithms :)

Comment: Thank you very much!This helped me a lot :)

Comment: How much is $C$ ? How much is $\ln C$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct since both $\ln(C)$ and $C$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 0):

The sets

$$\left\{x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}(\ln x - \ln(3-x) + C)| C\in\mathbb R\right\}$$

and
$$\left\{x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}(\ln x - \ln(3-x)) + C| C\in\mathbb R\right\}$$

are equal. That is, these are just two different ways of describing the same set of functions.

Comment: No, the answer from the book is ln C instead of just C.I don't get it

Comment: @NathanaelMiranda The set $$\left\{x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}(\ln x - \ln(3-x)) + C| C\in\mathbb R\right\}$$ is also equal to the set $$\left\{x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}(\ln x - \ln(3-x)) + \ln C| C\in\mathbb R_+\right\}$$

Comment: $\ln C$ takes on all values in ${\mathbb R}$, so, since $C$ may be chosen arbitrarily, it doesn't matter if you write it as $C$ or $\ln C$

Comment: oooooh.okay thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If fact, the correct result for the primitive would be
$$
\int \frac 1x dx = \ln |x| + K, \quad K \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

The absolute value is fundamental so that the domain of the primitive is the same as the domain of $\frac 1x$. Since $\log C$ can take any real value, you can choose to say that $K = \log C$.

Comment: This is not quite correct either.  We need K to be a locally constant function.  Since the domain has two connected components, we need to specify potentially different constants on each component.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Yes, you are correct but my point was just to introduce the need for the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the complete antiderivative is

$$
\begin{cases}
\ln(-x) - \ln(3-x) + C_1 \textrm{ if $x<0$}\\
\ln(x) - \ln(3-x) + C_2 \textrm{ if $0<x<3$}\\
\ln(x) - \ln(x-3) + C_3 \textrm{ if $3<x$}
\end{cases}
$$

Where $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are three (potentially) different constants.